# How to recover the data that has possibly overwriten by the installation of another system?

Tags: data-recovery

I had Linux mint installed in my computer in one partition and had another partition for Data.

I just installed Ubuntu Kylin 14.04 and during the installation there was an option like "install Ubuntu replacing Linux Mint", which was the one I chose, thinking it would just mess with the partition of Linux mint.

Now I boot in Ubuntu, and I have a huge partition with Linux (bootable), including the space that was before of the data partition...

Do I still have a chance to recover some stuff that was in my previous Data partition?

If so how can I do that?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I doubt that recovery after deletion is more or less the same like recovery after creating a new partition and a new file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to recover all my data which includes quite a few Gibabytes...

What I did:

1. booted the system with the USB installation disk in 'live mode'
2. installed the program testdisk
3. through it I was able to view and copy all the data I wanted to an external disk

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, while replacing the new operating system with old one, it actually formats the entire hard disk.

If you had chosen "install Ubuntu next to Mint" it would have been possible to have both OSs and your data as well.

In your case, since you chose to replace the OS, all the disk space was formatted and a new partition was created. So, it is not possible to recover your data partition.

Comment: Well, easily it is really unsalvageable, but a partition doesn't mean a whole overwrite in most cases.